# Tabbed Login/Register form refreshes if returns an error

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a Login form and a Register form on my website that is tabbed so by default on landing it is the login form. You can click the register form to make an account. However when there are errors on the Register form, (missing email etc) the tab goes back to the Login tab, almost like the page refreshes. I want it to stay on the Register form to show the errors so a user doesn't have to reclick on Registering. This is the php code I have to make the form work:

```
    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['password']) && empty($_POST['email'])){

        $register_errors[] = 'Email and Password fields are required.';

    } else {            

        if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
            $register_errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';
        } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 18){
            $register_errors[] = 'Your password cannot be more than 18 characters long';
        }
        if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password2']){
            $register_errors[] = 'The password you entered does not match the verified password.';
        }
        if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $register_errors[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        } else if ($users->email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
            $register_errors[] = 'That email already exists.';
        }
    }


    $captchaPass = false;

    if ($dev == false) {
        require_once('../core/classes/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
        $privatekey = "6Lc2UvoSAAAAAGDaMhEadIor9ZQeY4bJHpJmrhYD";
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if (!$resp->is_valid) {
            // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
            $register_errors[] = 'The passphrase you entered was inccorect. Please try again.';
        } else {
            $captchaPass = true;
        }

    } else { 
        $captchaPass = true;
    }       


    if (empty($register_errors) === true && $captchaPass === true){

        $firstName      = htmlentities($_POST['firstName']);
        $lastName       = htmlentities($_POST['lastName']);
        $country        = htmlentities($_POST['country']);
        $state          = ($country == "United States") ? htmlentities($_POST['state']) : '';
        $password       = $_POST['password'];
        $password_hash          = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 10));
        $email          = htmlentities($_POST['email']);

        $users->register($firstName, $lastName, $country, $state, $password_hash, $email);


        if (isset($_SESSION['order_id'])) {
            header('Location: ../order/checkout.php');
        } else if (isset($_POST['Location: ../stories/'])) {
            header('Location: ../stories/'.$_POST['return'].'/');
        } 
        else {
            header('Location: ../account/');
        }
        exit();
    }
}
 if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
  echo 'Thank you for registering. Please check your email.';
}
```

And this is the form action (the form is just standard inputs so leaving those out)

```
<form action="./" method="post" name="register_form" id="register_form" title="register_form" class="form">
```

My guess might be something with the form action going to ./ but not sure how to change that if it returns an error.

Comment: you can use Ajax for that. You can try `action=""` if your code's all in the same file.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the code but it is probably a bad idea to make something called "privatekey" public. It may or may not be abused.